# Python giving me an error for trying to mod two variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the lowest number that is divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20.

The problem is in `i%j == 0`. It's giving me this error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

even though I tried the same thing with a variable and a constant and it passes:

```
i % 2 == 0
```

My code:

```
i = 20
while True:
    k = 0
    for j in range(21):
        if i % j == 0:
            k += 1
    if k == 21:
        break
    i+= 1

print(i)
```

Comment: Try `20 % 0` and see what happens. Your code has the same problem.

Comment: I changed the j to j+1 and it's still giving me the same problem

Comment: Did you add parenthesis around `j + 1`?

Comment: No. but i did and it's fixed

Comment: But the output is not correct though

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach won't work for the time constraint - it'll just take too long to complete.

Try this code first and figure out what's the `trick` to save computing time.

```
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
prod = 1

for p in primes:
    n = 2
    prod *= p
    while (p**n < 21):
        prod *= p
        n += 1
print(prod)   # 232_792_560
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the `for-loops` to solve it. Here it's another alternative way:

```
i = 1
for k in (range(1, 21)):
    if i % k > 0:
        for j in range(1, 21):
            if (i*j) % k == 0:
                #print(i, j, k)        # for debug only
                i *= j 
                break 

print(f' loop-way: {i} ')  # 232792560
```